# How to change my url from https://example.com/name.html to https://example.com/name?

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-hosting

How to change my url from `https://example.com/name.html` to `https://example.com/name`?
I am using Firebase Hosting to host my website. The site is made in HTML and javascript using bootstrap studio.

After reading various solution online, i know that '.htaccess' file can be used to change the url but none of the solution provide a way to do it with Firebase Hosting.

Comment: What do you mean by "change your url"?  If you just want the file at /name.html to also appear at /name, you can probably use [rewrites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Hosting has a setting called `cleanUrls` that controls the presence/absence of the HTML extension. See the documentation on [controlling .html extensions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#control_html_extensions):

> The `cleanUrls` attribute allows you to control whether or not URLs should include the `.html` extension.

> When true, Hosting automatically drops the `.html` extension from uploaded file URLs. If an `.html` extension is added in the request, Hosting performs a `301` redirect to the same path but eliminates the `.html` extension.

> Specify the inclusion of `.html` extensions by including a cleanUrls attribute within hosting in your `firebase.json` file. For example:

> ```
> "hosting": {
>    // ...
>
>    // Add the "cleanUrls" attribute within "hosting"
>    "cleanUrls": true
> }
> ```